# How to create Modal and Modeless forms in borland c++ builder

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have an assignment to enhance an already existing tool written in Borland c++, I am new to programming and c++ builder. The task is to integrate message box which pops up, in to the main form itself,which I have successfully done by adding a new form to the project and calling it in place of message box.
I have made my new form modal so that control is blocked,till user selects an option.

Now I have added another form named graph to the project to show a graph and I want the control to go to the graph when user clicks a button in the new form.

Is there a way to make two children modeless and block only the parent form(modal).In short I want to access both the new forms I have added to my project and I don't want to access my main form,till I make all selections in these two forms.Kindly help!

Comment: Is there a way to make the children forms modeless and to block only the main form(modal) in Borland C++ builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `ShowModal()`, you could set the parent Form's `Enabled` property to false, use `Show()` to show both forms, and then set the parent Form's `Enabled` property back to true when both forms have been closed.

Comment: But that does not block the parent form from running rite? How can we make the parent form wait without showing dialog?

Comment: The parent form will still process messages (timers, painting, etc), but the user will not be able to interact with it while it is disabled. Also, if you are using an older version of C++Builder, you may have to override the secondary form's `CreateParams()` methods to specify the parent form as the parent `HWND` (from the Win32 API's perspective, not the VCL's) so those windows cannot disappear behind the parent form's window (the default is to use the `TApplication` window as the parent HWND instead, which allows TForm windows to change z-order in relation to each other)...

Comment: ...In newer versions, `TForm` and `TApplication` have new `PopupMode` and `PopupParent` properties available to control that issue better now. Meaning, you could set the second form's `PopupParent` properties to be the parent form, and then they will never be able to go behind it.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `PopupParent`, I've continually struggled with issues of windows being shown behind other windows they should be in front of (especially bad when the back window is modal, and the front one can't be moved because it's locked due to the back one being modal!)

Answer (score 0):

You could move the functions you don't want to run automatically during `create` from the `OnCreate()` method.  You may move them to e.g. `OnClick()`.  I faced a similar situation where a `Show()`
method was running during program `create`.  I implemented the `OnActivate()` method and  called the `Show()` method from there, instead from `OnCreate()`.